# Difference between Guidewire claimcenter version 6/8 and version 10

Tags: guidewire

What are the differences/features between guidewire claimcenter version 6/8 and version 10?

Answer (score 1):

Each release has release notes.  This does require access to Guidewire documentation.  This is an example for Self Managed ClaimCenter 10.0.0.

[ClaimCenter Self Managed Release Notes V10.0.0](https://docs.guidewire.com/self-managed/cc/1022/releasenotes/releasenotes1000.html)